# Как исключить несколько значений из запроса в базу?

Tags: php, mysql

Собираю все айдишники из таблицы

```
    $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idto SEPARATOR ',') as likedid FROM likes WHERE idfrom='$currentloginid'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ $likedid = $row["likedid"];} $result->free(); } else{ echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}
```

Выводятся как и задумано через запятую `626f309cbf57f,628e0cd453df8,6255c7ee8e5b1,628e15c635a69,62a80bc9d4aed,62a859a2950a8`. Потом результат использую для ещё одной выборки. Ругается на синтаксис: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cd453df8,6255c7ee8e5b1,628e15c635a69,62a80bc9d4aed,62a859a2950a8,62838b0c8b7e6,6' at line 1`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex!='$currentsex' && scum<10 && id not in ($likedid)";
```

Comment: зависит от того что в `$likedid` и какой в целом запрос `$sql` тут получается........ "ругается на синтаксис" не говорит ни одному человеку в мире ни о чём

Comment: В $likedid: `626f309cbf57f,628e0cd453df8,6255c7ee8e5b1`  и т.д. через запятую. Ошибка: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cd453df8,6255c7ee8e5b1,628e15c635a69,62a80bc9d4aed,62a859a2950a8,62838b0c8b7e6,6' at line 1`

Answer (score -1):

Как минимум нет закрывающей кавычки

должно быть так:
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex!='$currentsex' && scum<10 && id not in ($likedid)";`

а дальше уже смотрите, о чем конкретно говорят ошибки, возможно likedid пуста или там не применимый к sql-строке формат

Upd: Если поле id в таблице имеет тип "строка", то в самом запросе LIKE нужно каждое значение взять в кавычки. Должно получиться на выходе что-то типа `not in ('6255c7ee8e5b1','628e15c635a69','62a80bc9d4aed','62a859a2950a8')`

Comment: С ней тоже ошибка.

Comment: В таблице users поле id какого типа? Явно не INT. Если это строки, то в самом запросе LIKE нужно каждое значение взять в кавычки. Должно получиться на выходе что-то типа `not in ('6255c7ee8e5b1','628e15c635a69','62a80bc9d4aed','62a859a2950a8')`

Comment: Да, помогло, а как можно эти кавычки добавить в моём случае?

Comment: Желательно likedid иметь на входе массивом, тогда можно использовать такую конструкцию с implode

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex!='$currentsex' && scum<10 && id not in ('" . implode("','", $likedid) . "')";`

Если все же надо преобразовать уже готовую строку тогда так 

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex!='$currentsex' && scum<10 && id not in ('" . str_replace(",", "','", $likedid) . "')";`

Comment: Спасибо вы помогли

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку на моем ответе, если он Вам помог.